# {ApplicationName}/ScriptResource.axd and invalid viewstate

Tags: asp.net

I have an asp.net web form application running in a web farm?

All the machine keys are configured the same in web.config according to MSDN recommendation, still, it periodically throw out "System.Web.HttpException: Invalid viewstate.", and according to the stack.

It's in this line

Request : /{applicationname}/ScriptResource.axd +92

Note:{applicationname} is my application name.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Erratic Invalid Viewstate issue in a .NET application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728513/erratic-invalid-viewstate-issue-in-a-net-application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see [Erratic Invalid Viewstate issue in .net application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728513/erratic-invalid-viewstate-issue-in-net-application)