# Invalid viewstate: Missing field _VIEWSTATE

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I was curious why I keep seeing an error

`The client disconnected: Invalid viewstate`

with an inner exception of a large ViewState key followed by

```
System.Web.HttpException: Invalid viewstate: Missing field: __VIEWSTATE3
```

The number at the end of the __VIEWSTATE field changes depending on what chunk is missing.

The server is not in a cluster or a webfarm, and I'm just trying to understand why this error keeps occurring. I see it in our logs pretty frequently and just wondering why some of the ViewState chunks may not make it back to the server.

I've got the following set up in the web.config

`<pages maxPageStateFieldLength="8000">`

It seems like the smaller the size, the more frequently I will see this error as well. I've been unable to reproduce it whenever I've navigated to the site or used it for an extended period of time.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You have similar issue with mine. Do you manage to resolve it? Thanks.

Comment: Ok. Are you using IE7 or IE8?

Comment: Mine has problem when using IE7 and IE8. There is ok

Comment: I'm not sure as our clients use a variety of browsers

Comment: Ok. I manage to repro this issue. This is a bug from IE7 and IE8. 
You won't get it with IE9 above and other modern browsers. 
The details is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728513/erratic-invalid-viewstate-issue-in-a-net-application