# IE removes html?

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer

I am running a asp.net website with .net 3.5 on iis6 on windows server 2003 32-bit.

I have observed some strange exceptions lately that is related to (what it looks like) internet explorer removes html code.

For example, this html code

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.js" />
</head>
<body>
    some example text.
</body>
```

Can turn into this.

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.ome example text.
</body>
```

The example above is just an example, the amount of html that is removed is different, and also since this happens on all kind of pages the content will also be different.

I have not been able to reproduce this, but the errors is from multiple variations of IE (mostly ie8 but some ie7) (with and without toolbars). The problem never happens for other browsers such as firefox, chrome, opera.

The visitors come from different hosts and from different countries. The error doesn't seem to occur at specific times.

This problem is very rare and happens only for a few requests every day.

Comment: How have confirmed that this is actually occuring?  What tool are you using to detect what HTML is actually being loaded?

Comment: I get exceptions that it cannot find the file "stylesheet.ome example text".

I have not been able to fetch the html that is actually being loaded. But since I know that the file (stylesheet) that should be loaded, and I know the text that is on that page, and it has been merged, that is my best guess.

Comment: what does the declaration look like on the .aspx page at the top? For example, the doc type?

Comment: &lt;!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"&gt;

Answer (score 1):

This may be in IE8 only (masked by IE8's CompatView UserAgent emulation of IE7), and if so, it could be related to this thread: [IE 8 dropping memory pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835130/ie-8-dropping-memory-pages)