# HTTP Request Corruption

Tags: .net, http, browser

On a site that receives a very high amount of traffic some small percent of requests come like this:

```
http://cheezburger.com/ScriptResource.axd?d=zaVpgH63ePt90pn</a>                                                   <br />                        <br />                        <p>                            <a id=
```

On the page referrer page there is a line like so:

```
<script src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=zaVpgH63ePt90p8fuEYkPAKFZuziMYsiIUbmxDb-gQ23Cx78LNJNFXTqKciA4ND_frR-_r9UKsdtLPk6M08xyk6cXFSLUrbBGDlvPIf-F9w1&amp;t=ffffffffd5e08dd5" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and another couple lines much further on:

```
    <a id="login_LoginState_LoginButton" class="button1" UseSubmitBehavior="false" href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;login$LoginState$LoginButton&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;ctl00$Login1&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, true))">Log In</a>
<br /> 
<br /> 
<p> 
    <a id="login_LoginState_PasswordRecoveryLink" href="/forgot.aspx">Forgot Password?</a>
```

So it appears that part of the page has been removed. It appears to happen more often in IE than Firefox, but that might be because we have more IE traffic than FireFox. We have HTTP compression turned on, but I don't know if that is the problem.

So my question is what is going on and how can it be fixed?

Comment: Just for clarification, the closing <a> tag, <br>s and <p> tag come across in the requested url?

Comment: yeah, and it is unpredicatable so when this occurs we get random chunks of the page added onto part of the real Url. The original url is also usually truncated, so the resulting url is completely invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at the automatic bug reports generated by this error, it seems the majority of the cases where this occurs is with clients going through proxies. I think this comes down to either a bug in the proxy or a bug in the gzip implementation on the proxy.

Comment: I think this is most likely, specially if it's web proxies, which generally have to alter the page to replace the real URLs with some pointing to their service.

Comment: Have you looked at log files generated by the proxy?
Also it would be interesting to see if this still occurs if the proxy is bypassed.

Comment: I don't have access to the proxies or the clients, I just have a logger that logs the error.

Comment: One proxy service that had a bunch of them, was a satellite ISP.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got a bit of time to diagnose and time to spare this, I have a potential suggestion for more information gathering:

Write a javascript check on the length of the page after loading, and make sure that value is the same as what the server thinks.  If it isn't, check out whats going on. You could run this live, or run a browser farm against your server looking for the bug. This relies on the javascript check getting across intact, though.

This almost sounds like a bizarre network or server problem, which is why I'd suggest trying to get ahold of the client side's version of the page to see what they've got.

Comment: I think it is clear that the whole document isn't getting into the client browser.

Comment: Right, but it may be interesting to see what the document that did get there was and how often it happens.  Is it always the same section?

The only reason this is being detected is because it happens to occur during a link.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly this is due to the transmission of the page being chunked:

Paragraphs 3.5, 3.6 and 3.6.1 talk about how HTTP pages that use transfer-encoding like gzip must be chunked, unless they close the connection after the entire page has been sent.

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.5

I believe each chunk is independantly compressed, and one of those chunks might have gotten corrupt.

Comment: It would be great if this was the problem, but it isn't, because we would expect the breaks to be on chunk/page barriers. Also webservers gzip first and the chunk the output.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like one of the IE bugs. IE6 always had [problems with gzipped](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/837251) responses and IE8 introduced new issues with the [Lookahead Downloader](http://blogs.msdn.com/ieinternals/archive/2009/07/27/Bugs-in-the-IE8-Lookahead-Downloader.aspx).

I think you might be dealing with the ['Missing 4k Bug'](http://blogs.msdn.com/ieinternals/archive/2009/07/27/Bugs-in-the-IE8-Lookahead-Downloader.aspx) and the recommended workaround is to use a `Content-Type` HTTP header rather than a `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type"/>` tag for charset declaration.

More Links:

- [Microsoft Connect Entry with Response from Microsoft](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=434997&wa=wsignin1.0)
- [Related Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835130/ie-8-dropping-memory-pages)
- [Related Microsoft Connect Entry](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=467062)
- [My Problem that turned out to be caused by this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392970/httpserverutility-urltokendecode-fails-sometimes-invalid-length-for-a-base-64)

Comment: This occurs with both Firefox ans IE.

Answer (score -1):

Difficult to say by just looking at it.  It could be a framework that adds a session id for you as a fallback from cookie sessions.  The small percentage could be users with disabled cookies?

A similar thing happens in [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org) with JSession id.

Answer (score -2):

The "`&amp;`" is correct. It's in a `<Script>` tag so it's ok to be like that. Check the source of a Asp.Net AJAX-enabled page and you'll see it'll be in that form.

Do you have the requisite `<httpHandlers>` section in your 'Web.Config' with the `<add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" ... />` entry? I'm just wondering if your app knows how to handle .axd files?

@leonm - the "d" parameter is the encoded resource key, added by Asp.Net AJAX. The "t" is the timestamp, used to determine when the assembly was last modified.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do whether the html or script tag is well formed, since the wrong data is showing up in the browser source.