# HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenDecode fails "sometimes" (Invalid length for a Base-64 char array.)

Tags: c#, asp.net, base64

We have an `IHttpHandler` for stylesheets and add a `<link/>` tag to the page like this:

```
HtmlGenericControl link = new HtmlGenericControl("link");
link.Attributes.Add("rel", "stylesheet");
link.Attributes.Add("href", "stylesheet.axd?d=" +
                                    HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode(token));
head.Controls.Add(link);
```

In the `stylesheet.axd` handler, we `UrlTokenDecode` the `d` query string parameter like this:

```
var token = HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenDecode(Request.QueryString["d"]);
```

This works most of the time but every now and then we find one of the following two exceptions in our log:

```
[FormatException: Invalid character in a Base-64 string.]
   System.Convert.FromBase64CharArray(Char[] inArray, Int32 offset, Int32 length)
   System.Web.HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenDecode(String input)
   ...

[FormatException: Invalid length for a Base-64 char array.]
   System.Convert.FromBase64CharArray(Char[] inArray, Int32 offset, Int32 length)
   System.Web.HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenDecode(String input)
   System.Web.HttpServerUtilityWrapper.UrlTokenDecode(String input)
   ...
```

Any ideas what would cause this phenomenon?

Remarks:

- the resulting URL is < 1500, so below any known URL limits (e.g. IE: 2083)
- seems to be independent of user agent (we have these exceptions for IE6,7,8, FF & Chrome)
- our (unconfirmed) suspicions include AntiVirus products, HTTP proxies, browser addons
- found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858761/what-causing-this-invalid-length-for-a-base-64-char-array) remotely related question, but it's about a viewstate issue

Comment: did you get cause of this phenomenon? `FromBase64String` ?

Answer (score 0):

We had similar problems, so we avoided UrlTokenEncode, the reason is base64 sometimes pads trailing characters as '==' and so on, so they dont get transmitted in url correctly. And I think there is a bug in .NET, however we changed it to following and it started working.

We did this way and it worked always.

```
url += "&d=" + HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode( Convert.ToBase64String( ... ))
```

and at receiving side, we use only

```
data = Convert.FromBase64String( Request.QueryString["d"] )
```

We do not need to use UrlDecode, because the query string object stores information in decoded format already.

Comment: Don't build URLs or query strings using string formatting! It is so easy and so common to forget encoding, or doing it wrong, or adding multiple `?` instead of `&`, etc.

Use the following solution for building query strings: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1877016/2279059

Use `UriBuilder` for adding query strings to URLs.

Answer (score 0):

`UrlTokenDecode` and `UrlTokenEncode` do not actually decode/encode base64url, but can be used for it anyway with some additions. Also, there are alternatives which may or may not be better.

See [C#: base64url according to RFC4648](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26732145/c-base64url-according-to-rfc4648)