# Invalid length for a Base-64 char array during decoding/decryption

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, encryption

Q: I face the following big problem :

from time to another i find the following exception:

**Invalid length for a Base-64 char array**

*I use encryption and decryption:*

```
public static string Encrypt(string text)
        {

            try
            {
                key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringKey.Substring(0, 8));
                DESCryptoServiceProvider des = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
                Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
                MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream,des.CreateEncryptor(key, IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
                cryptoStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                return Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.ToArray());
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
              string message =  ex.Message;
            }

            return string.Empty;
        }



        public static string Decrypt(string text)
        {
            try
            {
                key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringKey.Substring(0, 8));
                DESCryptoServiceProvider des = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
                text = text.Replace(" ", "+")
                Byte[] byteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(text);
                MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream,
                des.CreateDecryptor(key, IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
                cryptoStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string message = ex.Message;

            }
```

i read many articles about the problem 
some posts talking about the solution is:

`text = text.Replace(" ", "+")`
and this not fixes my problem at all

my string is :`3DZF/NZpp0yuQ=3D`
please i need help to fix this problem.

**EDIT**

- **If there are any modifications or
  enhancements to this class to make it
  work better or more secure or avoid
  any possible problems like this , i
  will be grateful.**
- **If there are alternating classes instead of this,more
  secure and doesn't make these
  problems , I will be  grateful.**
- **I use this class in a small
  application used to verifying mails.**

---

EDIT:

```
Decoding the querystring values is done already when it's parsed into the Request.
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10879400/418343

Comment: A common problem is incorrectly stripping the padding (trailing equal signs) from the end of a string. In your case "=3d" is likely supposed to be simply "=" or perhaps "=="

Comment: Doesn't answer your question, but this is a really bad way of encrypting - sounds like you are doing the same thing as gawker. You are only using the first 8 characters as a key, and using DES (an outdated encryption standard) See http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/12/the-dirty-truth-about-web-passwords.html

Comment: A side-note: `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes` is a very bad and unsafe way to get a Key from a password.

Comment: Looks like @EricLaw is correct in that it should be `==`. Is this base64 string gathered from a query string? `%3D` is the URL-encoded form of `=`, so it looks like your problem lies with URL encoding

Comment: then what are the alternates to this class.. or how to fix this problem

Comment: is there an alternating class for encryption and decryption and doesn't make these errors.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925729/invalid-length-for-a-base-64-char-array. For Base64, the value should be multiples of 4

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To solve the problems you need to fist Encode and then Decode the all ready encode-base64 string, depend from where you using it.

If for example you use it on url (or query) where probably this is the place you going to use, then you need to Encode the URL before you use it, decode the url before you get it back. The reason is that you need to avoid to mix the same characters that URL use as code character, with the encrypted characters.

Anyway here is the code that solve your problem (and I use for the same reason):

```
public static string encodeSTROnUrl(string thisEncode)
{
    if (null == thisEncode)
        return string.Empty;

    return HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Encrypt(thisEncode));
}


public static string decodeSTROnUrl(string thisDecode)
{
    return Decrypt(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(thisDecode));
}
```

ps
I have the same problem, and have try as you say replace the '+' and other, but at the end this is what make it works.

Don't forget to remove the **text = text.Replace(" ", "+")**, and other manipulations of the encryption from your code, just encrypt and decrypt.

Comment: the string comes from a query string..is your method still do what i wanna to do

Comment: sorry please i'm confused little , can u tell me where to call these methods in my code.thanks in advance

Comment: @just_name, The Encrypt/Decrypt function that I call is your functions. Now on your code instead you call the Encrypt/Decrypt, you call the encodeSTROnUrl/decodeSTROnUrl.

Comment: ok thanks a lot  ...i will try your method , and i hope to fix this problem indeed.

Comment: @just_name yes it will solve it, I use to have the same problem, and after a lot of tests I end up with this. This now work on my sites for more than 3 years with out problem.

Comment: @Aristos: thanks alot , but please when i tried to encyrpt (7200406) i face the same exception , is this beacuse it is long number or what??

Comment: @just_name no this is not a long number, actually something else must be your issue.

Answer (score -2):

```
string imag = img;
imag = imag.Replace("\", "");
int c = imag.Length % 4;
if ((c) != 0)
    imag = imag.PadRight((imag.Length + (4 - c)), "=");
[] converted = Convert.FromBase64String(imag);
using (System.IO.MemoryStream vstream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(converted)) {
    return Image.FromStream(vstream);
}
```