# Should I encode the data before hashing it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, hash, encode, sha

Should I encode the data before hashing it to avoid `Invalid length for a Base-64 char array`.

# my .cs :

```
Stream des = file.InputStream;
byte[] data = new byte[file.ContentLength];
des.Read(data, 0, file.ContentLength);
FileStream f = new FileStream(targetFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
f.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
f.Flush();
f.Close();
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var sha = new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512Managed();
string hash2 = Convert.ToBase64String(sha.ComputeHash(data));
```

and if the answer is yes How to encode the byte array.

**Note:**

I use hashing to uniquely identify the uploaded files for any change.

Comment: @sehe while true, I don't think that relates to the context of the question, which is about **creating** a base-64 string. You don't pad inputs.

Comment: I face similar problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4555249/invalid-length-for-a-base-64-char-array-during-decoding-decryption .. And i fair to face the same problem if i hach before encoding my data

Comment: where exactly do you get the "Invalid length for a base-64 char array" error? I'm pretty sure it isn't in the code shown...

Comment: yeah not in this code . Any expected exceptions from this code ?and i will store `hash2` in my database to identify if any change did happen to my uploaded file from the last failure , should i store the byte array before conversion or storing  `hash2` perform the goal.

Comment: none; that should just work; storing `hash2` should work fine, as long as you store it robustly.

Comment: Thank U so much . i don't know what did u mean by `robustly`?

Comment: somewhere you are storing `hash2` yes? all I mean is that **when you fetch this value again**, double check (in a breakpoint etc) that you successfully got back **exactly** the same string that was produced by `ToBase64String`, and that you haven't damaged it during storage. If the string is intact, it will work fine. If it is erroring, the string has almost certainly not been stored/fetched correctly, but that is **unrelated** to the fact that it is base-64, and simply relates to your storage code.

Comment: I see, thanks U so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That error happens when **decoding** base-64, since a valid base-64 string is always a multiple of 4 characters (sometimes with a few padding chars). No, you do not need to encode/pad the **input** to `ToBase64String`. Rather, it sounds like you are losing some characters when you are **transporting** / **storing** it (are you perhaps passing it on a query-string, and having a `+` vs *space* issue?)