# how to solve Invalid length for a Base-64 char array?

Tags: c#, java

i will pass the string like `"1ijga8ZMQsjlN//74b+D9g=="` to the method for decryption than performed but when i will store that string into String variable and than pass the variable to the method than below error encounters:

Invalid length for a Base-64 char array.

Problematic Code:

```
String hdDec = Dispatch.call(c10, "Decrypt",hd, passPhrase, saltValue, hashAlgorithm, passwordIterations, initVector, keySize).toString();
```

Comment: Please show your actual code.

Comment: String hdDec = Dispatch.call(c10, "Decrypt","1ijga8ZMQsjlN//74b+D9g==", passPhrase, saltValue, hashAlgorithm, passwordIterations, initVector, keySize).toString();

Comment: when i am use variable like String hd="1ijga8ZMQsjlN//74b+D9g==" and then pass that string variable hd to method String hdDec = Dispatch.call(c10, "Decrypt",hd, passPhrase, saltValue, hashAlgorithm, passwordIterations, initVector, keySize).toString();

Comment: That base64 string is valid in itself. We've no idea what `Dispatch.call` is though, or what the myriad arguments are meant to mean...

Comment: Than above error encountered.all other variables like passPhrase,saltValue are initialized.so error is occurred only in string variable.

Comment: Dispatch.call is used to call from java to .net dll

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem you need to first `Encode` and then `Decode` the all ready encode-base64 string, depend from where you using it.

Please look to the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4555717/418343)

Answer (score 0):

The code you share does not provide enough information to solve this issue, because you only shared the code that *calls* the method that does all the work. However since the error message is

> Invalid length for a Base-64 char array.

the problem *may* be that you send a `string` and the method expects a `char[]`, so you could try `"1ijga8ZMQsjlN//74b+D9g==".ToCharArray()` instead. Otherwise all we can do is guess.

Comment: No.method accepts only strings and i have same 2 methods also but they run successfully only problem with this string,i dont no why??actually i am fetch the these string from address bar and stored in String variable and then i am pass that String variable to the webservice.and webservice call above code.

Comment: when webservice access these varible than that variable i want to pass in the method but above error occurred.

Comment: We don't know why either, but as the string is a valid base64 string, the problem is either one in of the other parameters (passPhrase, saltValue, etc) or in the code - you haven't provided those (don't copy/paste passwords from live websites!).

Comment: i find something.string above mentioned is actually original and when i am accessed that string through address bar than variable that stored that string is missed + sign in that so error is occurred because 1 character + missing.

Comment: i accessed that string in my website's address bar that i am actually working.