# Invalid length for a Base-64 char array while decryption 

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, base64, encryption

I get the following exception in some cases through (decryption) , and i can't recognize exactly the reason :

> Invalid length for a Base-64 char array

My Code  :

```
public static string encodeSTROnUrl(string thisEncode)
{
  if (null == thisEncode)
      return string.Empty;

  return HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Encrypt(thisEncode));
}


// string thisDecode = "3Dn%2bsJJPXprU4%3d"; //this is the value which cause the exception.
public static string decodeSTROnUrl(string thisDecode)
{
   return Decrypt(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(thisDecode));
}


QueryStringEncryption.Cryptography.decodeSTROnUrl(Request.QueryString["val"].ToString());
```

The exact line which throw the exception is :

```
 Byte[] byteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(text);
```

I thought i fix this problem by encoding and decoding before and after the encryption and the decryption operation.but some values still throw this exception .

---

Note: i note some strange behavior :
the id as a query string sent to my mail  is : `n%2bsJJPXprU4%3d` and it works without exceptions ..

and the user who has the problem the sent url contains `3Dn%2bsJJPXprU4%3d`

is this a browser problem ??!!

Comment: Can you post your entire code for `Encrypt` and `Decrypt`? Most likely you are doing some inappropriate encoding conversions (ASCII, Unicode) in between.

Comment: The whole code in this link :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4555249/invalid-length-for-a-base-64-char-array-during-decoding-decryption

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Decoding the querystring values is done already when it's parsed into the Request. try without 
'HttpUtility.UrlDecode'

```
public static string decodeSTROnUrl(string thisDecode)
    {
        return Decrypt(thisDecode);
    }
```

Comment: Who would have thought.  This was the solution for me!  Thanks @Damith!

Answer (score 4):

The 64-bit encoding has problems with spaces in the string.
Try to add the following after encrypting

```
sEncryptedString = sEncryptedString.Replace(' ', '+');
```

Comment: Unless a space and a plus sign represent the same character for OP, that's hardly the right solution.

Comment: @just_name, updated the response, I remembered it incorrectly. You need to change the encrypted result... OR (even better) right BEFORE you decrypt

Comment: The point is not to avoid the exception, but to decode the exact string you originally encoded, and this will not do it.