# System.FormatException: 'Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string.'

Tags: c#, base64, decode

I'm beating my head against a wall here, with this simple code that just doesn't work:

```
string middle = "eyJzdWIiOiJtYXR0d2ViZXIiLCJqdGkiOiJlMWVmNjc5Mi02YTBjLTQ4YWUtYmQzNi0wZDlmMTVlMDFiY2UiLCJpYXQiOjE0OTMwOTI0OTQsIm5iZiI6MTQ5MzA5MjQ5NCwiZXhwIjoxNDkzMjY1Mjk0LCJpc3MiOiJFQ29tbVdlYkFQSTIiLCJhdWQiOiJFQ29tbVdlYkNsaWVudDIifQ"

byte[] newBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(middle);
middle = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(newBytes);
```

It's that simple! And yet I get the error in the Title.

Also, I ran this on https://www.base64decode.org/ and it decodes perfectly.

Comment: Take a look on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925729/invalid-length-for-a-base-64-char-array

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since your provided string does not completely fit criteria of `FromBase64String` method accepted values you need to add end symbol to follow the convention. It does not automatically add end symbols to your `string`.

> The valueless character, "=", is used for trailing padding. The end of s can consist of zero, one, or two padding characters.

[Source.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string(v=vs.110).aspx)

To fix issue you are having add `"=="` to the end of your `string`.

For example: `string middle = "SomeString=="`

Comment: There is a bit more to that in general case as sometimes there is a need to add single '=' instead of 2 of them and some times the input string already "good to go" without any padding.

Answer (score 3):

To address the exception you are facing:

```
    public static string Base64UrlDecode(this string base64)
    {
        string padded = base64.PadRight(base64.Length + (4 - base64.Length % 4) % 4, '=');
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(padded));
    }
```

All credits goes to the accepted answer here [Code for decoding/encoding a modified base64 URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228701/code-for-decoding-encoding-a-modified-base64-url).

Comment: The problem arises when (base64.Length % 4 == 1). You can't have three '=' at the end. What can you do in that case?