# NodeRSA is not generate correct encrypted string for decrypt by RSACryptoServiceProvider C#

Tags: c#, node.js, reactjs, .net-core, rsa

My task is to encrypt data in frontend(reactJS) and decrypt it in the backend (.net core 2.0). I am using **NodeRSA** library in fronted and **RSACryptoServiceProvider** in the backend.

**Front end**

1. I generated two Keys(public and private).
2. Save both keys.
3. Then I import those keys and call to encrypt and decrypt methods in NodeRSA module.
4. Perfectly work both ways.

**Backend**

1. Generated two keys.
2. Keep it.
3. Use them and call to encrypt and decrypt methods in RSACryptoServiceProvider.
4. Awesome.

Then I use the public key which created by the frontend and generates the encrypted string. then I pass it to the backend and try to decrypt. but I got the error **"The parameter is incorrect"**
But when I used frontend public and private keys for encrypting and decrypt methods in the backend. those keys are working fine.

This is how I am trying

**Frontend (reactJS)**

```
 const key_public = new NodeRSA({ b: 1024 }); 
 key_public.importKey(public_key);
 let encryptedText = key_public.encrypt(this.state.secret, 'base64');
 console.log(encryptedText);
```

**Backend (.net core 2.0)**

```
    public string DecryptFromMyKey(string crypherText)
    {
        var dataBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(crypherText.Replace(" ", "+"));
        string privateXmlString = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?>....";
        RSACryptoServiceProviderExtensions.FromXmlString(csp, privateXmlString);
        var plainText = csp.Decrypt(dataBytes, false);
        var final = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(plainText);
        //string myKey = ExportPublicKeyToPEMFormat(csp, publicXmlString);
        return final;
    }
```

I check my keys and encrypted values with this site. https://8gwifi.org/rsafunctions.jsp. according to this site, my backend methods are doing their jobs correctly. It shows the correct plain text. but when I try it the encrypted text which created by the frontend. It not work.

Have I missed any coding part here? Is there any algorithm to add for frontend code?

Comment: Java has a different padding option than c#.  Padding is used on key to add random bytes to key so actual key size is hidden.

Comment: @jdweng: there is no Java anywhere in this question.

Comment: `crypherText.Replace(" ", "+")` What is going on here? I don't know of any base64 encoding that uses a space as an encoding character. Also, I don't believe that particular XML format is what RSACryptoServiceProvider is expecting. Also, according to the documentation I read, Node RSA uses OAEP padding by default. If so, then this `csp.Decrypt(dataBytes, false);` needs to be changed to `csp.Decrypt(dataBytes, true);`

Comment: @PresidentJamesMoveonPolk If While I am passing encrypted text from frontend to backend I am getting error ["Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string."](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2925959/3962409)  that's why I used `crypherText.Replace(" ", "+")` . XML part I used to add my private key to RSACryptoServiceProvider instance. I will try again to add this by PEM. I tried by changing my code into `csp.Decrypt(dataBytes, true);` but same error occurred.

Comment: It sounds like your data is getting corrupted in transit. I can't help you with that, sorry.