# ASP.Net: IE6 making invalid requests

Tags: internet-explorer-6, asp.net-2.0, webresource.axd

I have a live site where every error is logged and e-mailed to me.

I've been getting a lot of "Padding is invalid and cannot be removed." errors on requests to WebResource.axd. Looking closely, the request is erroneous.

This is the request in question:

```
/webresource.axd?d=mgqvdy8omlq71j1set2ida2&ampt=633700045603820000
```

And this is how it should look:

```
/WebResource.axd?d=MgQvdy8OmLQ71j1SET2IdA2&amp;t=633700045603820000
```

Notice the lack of capitalization and, more importantly, the lack of ; after &amp.

The user agent is this:

```
UA: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)
```

What could this be?
Could a real, actual user be getting errors because of this?
Is this something that IE could actually be doing wrong?
Or is this just a badly written bot?

This happens every now and then, it *definitely* doesn't happen to all our users, or even to all our IE users.

---

**UPDATE:** I'm also getting a lot of "Invalid character in a Base-64 string." when forms are posted, also only from IE 6.0, so i'm guessing they're related.

Thanks for your help!
Daniel

Comment: I'm getting the same thing on my ASP.NET MVC site.

Comment: another thought, is this site advertised in Google AdWords?

Comment: Is your site running in a web farm?

Comment: I had this exact same issue today and it was fixed by implementing Darin Dimitrovs answer (found elsewhere). You've not specified, but I have a server farm and the machine key's just need to be in sync.

Comment: You are correct it could also be an issue with bots/hackers. We get similar messages about invalid viewstate quite a bit sometimes running into the thousands and then suddenly they stop for a few days. Never been able to replicate it.

Comment: I don't have a server farm, this is a single server. The problem is that IE6 (or some proxy, or something, although if it's a proxy, I wonder why I only get IE6 UA's) is screwing up the content it sends to the server, either the URL or the POST data, it's not the server not being able to "decrypt" it.

Answer (score 2):

We were seeing similar errors with ScriptResource.axd and Invalid Viewstate exceptions.  Eventually I found this post:

1. [Error : /ScriptResource.axd : Invalid viewstate.](http://www.31a2ba2a-b718-11dc-8314-0800200c9a66.com/2009/04/error-scriptresourceaxd-invalid.html)

Which indicated a bug in IE (and possibly other browsers) where an invalid DOCTYPE of XHTML causes the browser to make an incorrect request to ScriptResource.axd.  We solved the problem by changing the XHTML DOCTYPE to the HTML5 doctype and removing the xmlns attribute from the html tag.  Our pages were not XHTML compliant anyway.

From:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
```

To:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you've already set a fixed MachineKey in your web.config, then this issue is most likely proxies messing up the requests. We get it with some of our IE6 users as well, and I've also seen where proxies turn & into &amp; in the querystring (which is incorrect).

Answer (score 1):

Just guessing here, but I had a similar problem with special characters being removed/substituted when I used IIS 7 to run some sites. Turned out to be IIS's "security feature" - its rules are in "urlscan.ini". Maybe this will help.

Answer (score 0):

As this is semi-random, the second option in [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/carloc/archive/2008/12/18/padding-is-invalid-an-cannot-be-removed-or-webpartmanager-is-undefined.aspx) may help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! 
Do you mean the hardcoded CSS values? I've definitely not put anything like that in our stylesheets, and we're not using any "packaged contronl" that outputs this kinds of things (like BasicDatePicker does, for example). If that's not what you meant, sorry if I didn't understand

Comment: Are you saying that "/webresource.axd?d=mgqvdy8omlq71j1set2ida2&ampt=633700045603820000" is the exact request causing the error every time? I'm not saying it's necessarily hard-coded CSS, but what kind of resource does that request produce?

Comment: Nope, it's not always the same URL generating the error. The actual resource changes. What always happens is that &amp; will be converted to &amp (missing the semicolon), and it's being made lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

Since the URL appears to be manipulated, it looks like it is a bug in a proxy software. Maybe you can find patterns in the requesting IP Ranges to identify certain proxies or ISPs.

However, that does not really explain the constant IE6 UserAgent (unless the proxy screws that up too). It could be one of the many IE bugs (e.g. gzip issues, Missing 4k Bug, etc.) but those usually break much more than just lowercasing an URL and remove one character. You could temporarily turn off gzip to see if it has any effect.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392388/http-request-corruption) is a question with similar symptoms and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392388/http-request-corruption/1475736#1475736) includes links to some of the IE bugs.

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting a fixed machineKey in your web.config file. For this you can use a [machineKey generator](http://www.orcsweb.com/articles/aspnetmachinekey.aspx) or generate your own:

```
<system.web>
    <machineKey
        validationKey='SOME KEY'
        decryptionKey='OTHER KEY'
        validation='SHA1'/>
</system.web>
```

Comment: don't have a server farm, this is a single server. The problem is that IE6 (or some proxy, or something, although if it's a proxy, I wonder why I only get IE6 UA's) is screwing up the content it sends to the server, either the URL or the POST data, it's not the server not being able to "decrypt" it.

Answer (score 0):

You could check:

-doctype (does it match the data you're sending? IE6 is picky)

-character set