# Trying to upload a file with ASP.NET MVC Error invalid character in a base-64 string

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Try to upload file using asp.net mvc error occured  "invalid character in a base-64 string".

Comment: What code are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Without code I can only google for you. Here're the links:

http://delroger.wordpress.com/2008/08/19/invalid-character-in-a-base-64-string-aspnet/
["Invalid Character in Base-64 String" using ASP.NET and C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051013/invalid-character-in-base-64-string-using-asp-net-and-c)
[ASP.Net: IE6 making invalid requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523546/asp-net-ie6-making-invalid-requests)

All about different causes and reasons. Pick yours or post the code.